# Move a div up and down based on mouse Move

Tags: scroll, mouseevent, mouselistener

I have this aside element which is has a `position:fixed;` property. Inside it, i have another `div.inner` which will hold elements which might be many and therefore might exceed the `window.height();`

Now, i need to solve this problem based on mouse scroll event on the `div.inner` element. I need to move the inner div top or down based on mouse scroll up or down events.

Please have a look at this [website](http://www.h15boutiqueapartments.com/) which demonstrates exactly what i need on the left were they have the logo and menus. Try moving your mouse up or down on that element and see.

[Here](http://codepen.io/joeyma/pen/MKwRRm) is my attempt which didn't go so well.

Comment: I would use pageY instead of pageX when handing the mouse event. ;-)

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer indeed mate. thanks a bunch. i overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Im not gonna write the entire code, but the concept from the page is:

```
pageHeigth = 200px
menuHeight = 250px
menuOverflow = menuHeight - pageHeight (50px)
Mouse positioned at the top: Menu CSS = "top:0px"
Mouse positioned at the bottom: Menu CSS = "top:-50px" (negative menuOverflow)
```

And of course interpolate the postion between top/bottom depending on mouse position. And also, using the terminology "mouse scroll" in your question makes it ambigous to understand, i believe "mouse move" is a better wording. "Scroll" makes me think about mousewheel or the page scrolling

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have edited the terminology as you have suggested.